# How Can i change write my method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
 public renameJson(json: any): any {
    return Object.keys(json).reduce(
      (s, item) =>
        this.isUpperCase(item.charAt(1))
          ? {
              ...s,
              [item.toLowerCase()]: this.getTransform(json[item])
            }
          : {
              ...s,
              [this.getFirstLetterToLowerCase(item)]: this.getTransform(
                json[item]
              )
            },
      {}
    );
  }
```

I wrote this method in typescript, but I am bothered by duplicate content. I would like to write it better, more or less like this:

```
public renameJson2(json: any): any {
    return Object.keys(json).reduce(
        (s, item) =>
        {
            ...s,
            [
                this.isUpperCase(item.charAt(1))
                ? item.toLowerCase()
                : this.getFirstLetterToLowerCase(item)
            ]
            : this.getTransform(json[item])
        },
        {}
    );
}
```

but my compiler says it's a mistake and i don't know why.

Comment: Have you considered doing a `forEach` over the keys and building the object one key at a time instead of rebuilding a new object each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different things going on here.

TL;DR:

```
interface IPojo {
  [key: string]: any
}

class Foo {
  public getTransform(...xs: any[]) {
    return xs;
  }

  public renameJson2(json: IPojo): IPojo {
    return Object.keys(json).reduce(
      (obj: IPojo, item: string, ...xtra: any[]) => {
        const [first, ...rest] = item.split('');
        // I don't have your other methods, so replace this
        // regex check if you wish.
        const key = first.match(/[A-Z]/)
          ? item.toLowerCase()
          : first.toLowerCase() + rest.join('');

        obj[key] = this.getTransform(json[item]);
        return obj;
      }, {}
    );
  }
}
```

You'll have to fill in getTransform yourself, but here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2ArTyDeAUMsgNoDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gLp1whWEC+hhBABs49esgBimPERIAHAK4AjIcATIWEMABUoXejExQAtgAoAdJYAe9Tt1JsAlAWIlkULQqghkNgNyu-K6KKmruECBwxhAAUvSYIABMptjxIHQYOJiOGVi4Lm7hYF4+APJK2BAIYOaUVPQpaY7mHgAmCkimroWmmBW5WQA0yMCQxnSMzCAsw5bmVkxwdlQOzgC8AHwFhW4ICYxkMMBQjLOWHoxsyGsjY+b0cqpgpgDkL44BO7v7YMh118gjicasY4GAEAALUwAelIAEEALQALTY0Mc3S+yAA-LcIMZzGBMAAZTAAd2gAGFRBBTOjMW46EDGATiWTKdTacgANThZm4UCvd4BDGFPrYCjUK43MAQ4D0cyaHR6EAGIxmVIJUijPFOT6YjzFbzIMV6wq8Yb4fiFD6BPhAA)

Problems with the original:

1. A returned object from an arrow function with no body should be wrapped in parens to avoid the parser confusing it with the body of the function.
2. The callback to `Array.prototype.reduce` gets *four* arguments (accumulator, item, theArray, thisValue), not two.
3. Using `any` in your signatures would have involved lots of casting, so I added a generic object interface.
4. Concision is nice, but readability is nicer. Don't be afraid of temp variables where they make sense, also on an array method the Jitter will probably optimize them out of existence after the first pass or two.

Comment: Point 2 doesn't matter.  TS doesn't care if you ignore extra parameters (and neither does JS).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the curly brackets that you intend for the object being constructed are being treated as the curly brackets of the `reducer` function. You can just add a `return` statement in your reducer function for the object like this -

```
 return Object.keys(json).reduce(
    (s, item) =>
    {
       return { ...s,
        [
            this.isUpperCase(item.charAt(1))
            ? item.toLowerCase()
            : this.getFirstLetterToLowerCase(item)
        ]
        : this.getTransform(json[item]) 
        }
    },
   {}
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to fix the issue you're seeing.  The issue is when you use curly braces after an arrow function, JS expects a function body to appear.  So this is effectively what you're writing

```
return Object.keys(json).reduce(function (s: any, item: any) {
  ...s,
  [
    this.isUpperCase(item.charAt(1))
      ? item.toLowerCase()
      : this.getFirstLetterToLowerCase(item)
  ]
  : this.getTransform(json[item])
});
```

I converted the arrow function to a normal function so you could see what TS is seeing.

To fix that issue, you can do one of two things.  Either [wrap the object in parenthesis](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQBO8AdmALbwBSEA9lQEwAUAVi1QFzQwVAJ4BKAUOFpM2WZSR5yVaAHkCXeMCQA6ANbxhEbr1HbKAEzzB4HGbPvQOECSIA00Ykni0XY6AF4APjsHbA4MUMj7bRiIVxCo0IBtBMSopAALYghtbIBVHBx4cgBhSBtPb21gDLByAEEkDgBGUVFUtNCAfg8vWm0kZgAZZgB3YrKIG3bOzoFM7O0Ac3gkADFicmQh1a9yWGGxifKOStoZ2YcAXQ7Z+ayclaRYciEIADNmclpjViSzq4XRIAX1E8U6qGBt1EAG4QlCQjhyMQAG5gLweCAFIqlE7IcgCfHEKhLcTQAjMZggeBCaSReSKZRIch4eBw2QI2RI1Ho+DQJ4bLZIHZIPYHEbjXFTU59XxkokkumhBlKaAAcjV7OwnOw3LRGKeLzen2+Mu8ct8SocKuUkK1WChwKAA) or [wrap the object in a function body and return it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQBO8AdmALbwBSEA9lQEwAUAVi1QFzQwVAJ4BKAUOFpM2WZSR5yVaAHkCXeMCQA6ANbxhEbr1HbKAEzzB4HGbPvQOECSIA00Ykni0XY6AF4APjsHbA4MUMj7bRiIVxCo0IBtBMSopAALYghtbIBVHBx4cgBhSBtPb21gDLByAEEkDgBGUVFUtNCAfg8vWm0kZgAZZgB3YrKIG3bOzoFM7O0Ac3gkADFicmQh1a9yWGGxifKOStoZ2YcAXQ7Z+ayclaRYciEIADNmclpjViSzq4XRIAX1E8U6qGBt1EAG4QlCQjhyMQAG5gLweCAFIqlE7IcgCfHEKhLcTQAjMZggeBCaSReSKZRIch4eBw2QI2RI1Ho+DQJ4bLZIHZIPYHEbjXFTU59XxkokkumhBlKaAAcjV7OwnOw3LRGKeLzen2+Mu8ct8SocKuUkK1WChwKAA).

Now, a suggestion for doing this a little more efficiently.  Simply use `forEach` and an object that can accumulate the properties instead of `reduce` and recreating the object each time ([playground snippet](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQBO8AdmALbwBSEA9lQEwAUAVi1QFzQwVAJ4BKAUOFpM2WcFbIKiPCCQSR0ALxoAvgG50M2VgDyBLvGBIAdAGt4wiN16jrAM2bkAomGAALDg57YQFkcmIqAHNRLQA+aWNE6HkqRUoIFSQAaQctaCQ-YghrIoBVHBx4cgBhSHggh2t-MHIAQSQOAEZRGIB+aGDrJGYAGWYAdyraiHqYgQKi60j4JAAxYnJkEZWkKthRiam6hrEDIySsdMyAbSvVHOEAXTyF4uWkWHIhCA9yWmdWNdgo9RAYLjpQedZFDsJQkHhyFQlBlVGDsDpDLIcOEAG5gXbQMoVI4zDhhUJIcJRcTQAjMZggeBCBJJOEIpGUvDwNFYDHnbHEPEE97rTZIbZIXbkfZjSY1Y7EXa0dRiClUyIsxJsxHQADkup50D5WNx+Pg0Hen2+v3+ivgysEIhpkk1xm1SNQ+nOGJ0QA))

```
public renameJson2(json: any): any {
    const result: any = {};

    Object.keys(json).forEach((key: string) => {
        const resultKey = this.isUpperCase(key.charAt(1)) ? key.toLowerCase() : this.getFirstLetterToLowerCase(key);

        result[resultKey] = this.getTransform(json[key]);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because arrow functions are waiting for curly braced characters `{}` after the arrow `=>`, but you want to return the curly braced object itself. I would suggest wrapping your object with parenthesis, like the following:

```
public renameJson2(json: any): any {
    return Object.keys(json).reduce(
      (s, item) => ({
        ...s,
        [this.isUpperCase(item.charAt(1))
          ? item.toLowerCase()
          : this.getFirstLetterToLowerCase(item)]: this.getTransform(json[item])
      }),

      {}
    );
  }
```